# Error after upgrading Gradle to 4.1 from 3.3 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle

I was using gradle 3.3 as in Gradle wrapper properties and I tried to build the apk, and it was showing the error that gradle version isn't supported and upgrade gradle to use this feature. So I upgraded the gradle to 4.1 using this statement in gradele wrapper properties.
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
And while I was emulating the application in my mobile, there was no error and an error occured on opening a new activity on a click from cardview.
The error was at setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz); and when I'm running a backup copy of the same project having gradle of 3.3 everything works fine, but I'm unable to create apk file

Answer (score 0):

You also need to open project `build.gradle` and modify buildscript->dependencies->classpath to as below

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

first try to clear you're android studio caches `file>invalidate caches/restart>validated and restart` from there you can clean project in `builds>clean project` and try to rebuild project in `builds`